# Heroku rake db:structure:load with cleardb can't find 'mysql'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, cleardb, sharetribe

I am trying to install an instance of Sharetribe on a heroku dyno. I am at the point where I am trying to create the database. I first tried rake db:migrate and it worked for most of the migrations but failed on one of them.

I was advised to use rake db:structure:load, so I tried that and I am getting an error from Heroku saying that mysql needs to be added to the PATH variable. Why is this, and how can I fix it? I'm not sure why it happens on db:schema:load and db:structure:load but not on db:migrate.

The complete stack trace with the error message is:

```
rake aborted!
failed to execute:
mysqlPlease check the output above for any errors and make sure that `mysql` is installed in your PATH and has proper permissions.

/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:148:in `run_cmd'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:72:in `structure_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:189:in `structure_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:222:in `load_schema_for'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:236:in `block in load_schema_current'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:276:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `each_current_configuration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:235:in `load_schema_current'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:293:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:structure:load
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run `heroku run bundle exec rake db:structure:load` than you need to install `mysql` client.
To install additional packages you need to add [Buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) (official or community based).

For mysql I successfully used https://github.com/din-co/heroku-buildpack-mysql

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/din-co/heroku-buildpack-mysql
git commit --amend --allow-empty --no-edit
git push heroku -f
```

Comment: Unable to push code heroku, got following error "cannot create /tmp/build_5263549fb7972f391b94a0afd55680d0/.profile.d/mysql.sh: Directory nonexistent"

Answer (score -2):

Heroku doesn't support `mysql`, you need to use `pg` gem in your gemfile in production block.
Please read [Getting Started with Rails 5.x on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#database)

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that Heroku doesn't host MySQL databases themselves. I'm trying to connect to a cloud database hosted with ClearDB through the Heroku ClearDB addon though. It is absolutely possible and peopel do it, but I'm not sure why there is a problem with it in this instance.

Comment: So I assume you have completed all steps from here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb is it? And did you remove/delete pg gem and/or addon?

Comment: I did, but heroku never displayed the postgres addon as existing on my dyno.